# Action class is not working in selenium 3.3.0

Tags: selenium

Automation script not able to right click on a webelement using selenium 3.3.0 on firefox 52 (64 bit). Script worked in IE11 but in firefox nothing happens.
Used geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64.
I have windows 10 and 64 bit OS.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Code given below:

```
WebElement predictresult = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "//div[@class='QvFrame Document_CH07']/div[@class='QvContent']/div[@class='QvGrid']/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.contextClick(predictresult);

action.build().perform();

Thread.sleep(3000);

WebElement selectexcel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='cf ctx-menu-action-XL']/a/span"));

selectexcel.click();
```

Comment: Update geckodriver and try

Comment: Tried with geckodriver-v0.16.0-win64 and throwed an error org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{elementScrollBehavior=1, marionette=true, browserVersion=52.

Comment: I got right click working in latest Firefox version(>56) and upgrading to Selenium 3.6. Thanks for your time

Comment: Glad it works for you :)